# Custom List Form with SharePoint Designer 2010 after default form was customized with InfoPath

Tags: infopath, list-form

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2010.  I've customized the default form with InfoPath 2010 for two reasons:

- Better display for the business.
- Hide some fields that the users shouldn't be able to set upon creation (I know this can be achieved with a custom aspx form).

I need to create an "Advanced Edit" aspx form to allow "administrator" type users the ability to edit the fields that are not on the custom InfoPath form (i.e. after the item is created).  When I try to create the "Advanced Edit" aspx form using SharePoint Designer, I get a message from SPD "Could not save the list changes to the server" and am not able to create the form.  I checked ULS and I see the following:

```
    HTTP request URL: /subweb/_vti_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=DisplayPost   953116bd-2173-4933-a383-5caa430d7fc1

The ListFormBody attribute in the forms schema was found but no child elements exist. Failed with 0x80004005, web web http://myserver:1001/subweb, list {40641AF6-2906-4771-9826-AFE40A9EF5E8}  953116bd-2173-4933-a383-5caa430d7fc1

CITPProj::AppendFormSchema failed with 0x80004005.  Type is DisplayForm, FormID is 0, web http://myserver:1001/subweb, list {40641AF6-2906-4771-9826-AFE40A9EF5E8}.  Ignoring failure and will continue.    953116bd-2173-4933-a383-5caa430d7fc1
```

Once I associate an InfoPath Form with my list, am I no longer able to create regular aspx forms?

-Brian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, it appears that after you customize the list form with InfoPath, you cannot make new forms with SharePoint Designer (SharePoint 2010 + December 2011 CU).

So what I did...

1. Recreate the list
2. Create the edit form (and associated custom action with EditListItems permissions mask)
3. Customized the InfoPath form.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create another view in the InfoPath form that shows the fields for Advanced Edit? You can have more than one view in an InfoPath form and you can set up rules that govern who can get to these views.

Comment: I tried this quickly, but couldn't get it going.  Plus this view would show for regular users creating things.  The idea is to prevent users from seeing the other fields in any view.